# A conjecture regarding linear Diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

*Proposition*:

Given a positive integer $n \geq 2$ and an $n-$dimensional vector $v=(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, with the vector satisfying the following properties:

1. $v_i > b$ for $i=0,1,2, \dots , n$ and a fixed $b\in \mathbb{N}$
2. the set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is pairwise relatively prime, i.e. $gcd(v_i, v_j) = 1$ for $i, j \in \{1, 2, \dots , n\}$

Then the linear Diophantine equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_ix_i = 0$ only admits zero solutions ($x_i = 0$) with the constraints $|x_i| \leq b$

It is certainly ture for $n=2$, what about the case $n \geq 3$?

Comment: $(-2)\times 5 + 1 \times 7 + 1\times 3 = 0$, where $3,5,7 > 2 \ge |-2|, |1|$, and $3,5,7$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @player3236 WOW, you make me look stupid. Thanks.

Comment: @player3236 can we impose any more constraints such that the conclusion holds at the end?

Comment: I don't think so, in fact $p -2q + r = 0$ holds (perhaps) infinitely often if we let $q$ be a [Balanced Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_prime), so the constraints must exclude these primes. Moreover as $n$ increases, the equation becomes *easier* to satisfy as there is "more wiggle room".

Comment: But $v_i=(b+1)^i$ will do the job.